# How can i delete certains regions of an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've this image with differents regions from which i want to eliminate by index.

[image: regions]

The numbers are place with this code:

```
[labeled,numObject] = bwlabel(I12S,8);
stats = regionprops(labeled,'Eccentricity','Area','BoundingBox','centroid','Pixelidxlist');
areas = [stats.Area];
eccentricities = [stats.Eccentricity];

idxOfSkittles = find(eccentricities);
statsDefects = stats(idxOfSkittles);

figure(47);
hold  on;
for idx=1 : numObject
           if(idx==22 || idx== 34 || idx==50) %%index I want to delete
               
           else
                text(stats(idx).Centroid(1),stats(idx).Centroid(2),num2str(idx),'Color', [0.89, 0, 0]);
           end
           hold on;
end
imshow(labeled);
```

Its not finished, I can't figure out how to get the index of the blob and delete it.
[image: aproximate result (painted)]

Comment: I dont understand what the desired output is. The upper and lower picture are the same

Comment: There is difference, sorry not to point it out, the regions 22 and 50 are gone.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your labeled image, or at least your original binary image. The pixel values of the labeled image should be equal to the index of the blob (that's what labeling does). Using that image, you can just zero out all pixels with the desired value like `labeled(labeled == idx) = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

`L` contains index of region (connected body of white pixels) that each pixel belongs to.

```
I = im2bw(imread('blobs.png'));
L = bwlabel(I,8);
I2 = I;
I2(L==22 | L== 34 | L==50) = false; % this is how
imshowpair(I, I2);
```